# How to turned off the translation on the node reference with entity translation?

Tags: 7, feeds, i18n-l10n, nodes

I have a multilingual site and I am using the feed module to import content. My site has two languages:

English and Arabic.

During import the node from excel value all the fields value save except node reference field value in Arabic language.

Previously i am having same issue for term reference. But it is solved by disabling `Select taxonomy terms by language` on  "`admin/config/regional/i18n/select`". But Node reference issue still there is there any settings present for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer.

There is an option for "Select nodes by language" in "admin/config/regional/i18n/select".

I just unchecked it. my issue has been solved.